# Qt's unique patterns

Tags: qt, design-patterns

I am working at the moment with Qt and discovered signals and slots. I think this is a Qt specific pattern. I am wondering if there are more Qt **specific patterns** like signals and slots. Are there any? Is there any specification about them?

**In addition:**

Qt's specific pattern are splitted in two parts:

Qt providing special classes for using design patterns like the Qt Quick module, Signal Slots..

The second part is the structure of some classes for example: QWidget

QWidget inherits from QObject which implements the composite pattern.

For further information i recommend this book: http://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Patterns-Prentice-Software-Development/dp/0132826453

Comment: It's not unique... However their approach of implementing it was. If not unique, at least pretty interesting. It's called event driven programming and some languages have native support for it (e.g. CLI languages such as C# and VB.NET).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some features which are unique to Qt or at least few implementations exist in other languages.

To name a few other than the signal-slot mechanism :

- **The Qt Quick module** : Enables you to write QML applications and  provides everything needed to create a rich application with a fluid and dynamic user interface. Some features are The Visual Canvas, User Input, States, Transitions And Animations, Particles And Graphical Effects, ...
- **Qt's Undo Framework** : It's based on command pattern for implementing undo/redo functionality in applications.
- **The State Machine Framework** : Can be used to effectively embed the elements and semantics of statecharts in Qt applications. It integrates with Qt's meta-object system; for example, transitions between states can be triggered by signals, and states can be configured to set properties and invoke methods on QObjects.

Comment: There's also Qt's Model/View Programming, which is a version of the Model / View / Controller pattern: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

Comment: Where can i find all those patterns?!

Comment: @Leviathan You can use Qt Quick  by adding `QT += qml quick` to your .pro file. Qt's Undo Framework is part of QtWidets module in Qt5 and the State Machine Framework is part of QtCore. You can find lots of information and examples by googling.